# Friendship vs inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend, protected, access-control

I've the class hierarchy below. Basically, I would like to establish a "has-a" relationship between the classes Foo and CComplexMat, i.e. class Foo "has-a" CComplexMat.
From what I know, `private` and `protected` members of a class cannot be accessed from outside the class where they are defined.

However, there are two possibilities to allow other classes to access such members.
The first one is to use `friend` classes. I could add a line `friend class Foo<T>;` in the declaration of `class CComplexMat<T>`, so that
`Foo<T>` can access the `protected` and `private` members of `class CComplexMat<T>`.

The second possibility would be to use `inheritance`, which is the solution that I've chosen in the example. In this case, I'm considering a `public` inheritance so that
both `public` and `protected` members of `class CComplexMat<T>` are accessible in class `Foo<T>`. However, the following error is shown:

`error: ‘CMatrix<float>* CComplexMatrix<float>::m_pReal’ is protected`

`error: within this context`

1. I was wondering if somebody could shed some light on the bug?
2. In which situations are "friendships" or "inheritances" more suitable?

```
template <class T>
class CMatrix{
    public:
     ...
        CMatrix<T> & operator = (const CMatrix<T> &);
        T & operator()(int, int, int);
        T operator()(int, int, int) const;
     ...
    private:
       T *** pData;
       int rows, cols, ch;
};

template <class T>
class CComplexMat: public CMatrix<T>{
    public:
    ...
    protected:
        CMatrix<T> *pReal;
        CMatrix<T> *pImag;
};

template <class T>
class Foo: public CComplexMat<T>{
    public:
        ...
        void doSomething(){
           ...
           CMatrix<T>*pTmp = pComplex->pReal; // error here.
           ...
        }
    ...
    private:
        CComplexMat<T> * pComplex;
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheritance should only be used for "is-a" relationships.  It looks to me like `CComplexMat<T>` has two `CMatrix<T>` members, but it's not the case that it "is-a" `CMatrix<T>`.  Similar deal with `Foo` and `CComplexMat<T>`.

So inheritance is almost certainly not the correct solution.  That leaves:

- Use `friend` to allow access between closely related classes.
- Use public accessor methods to allow users of a class to "get at" private members in limited ways.

For example, `CComplexMat<T>` should probably have private members for the real and imaginary parts but then also some accessors like:

```
public:
    const CMatrix<T>& realPart() const;
    CMatrix<T>& realPart();
    const CMatrix<T>& imagPart() const;
    CMatrix<T>& imagPart();
```

Comment: +1, you were just 30 seconds quicker than me with this suggestion

Comment: Thanks, for your suggestion. In regard to the getters, the `const .... const;` method means that the content of the object is not going to be modified. What about the other getter? In the case, I have overloaded the `operator()` in `CMatrix<T>`, can I use it as a `l-value` in `CComplexMatrix`, e.g. `(*this->m_pReal)(y,x,ch)=something`?

Comment: Yes, code in `CComplexMatrix<T>` will be able to do `(*this->mpReal)(y,x,ch) = expr` (assuming `operator()` returns `T&`).  Other code will be able to do `complexMat.realPart()(y,x,ch) = expr` only when `complexMat` is not `const`.

Comment: For both type of getters, I just need to return the pointer to the private member, right?

Comment: @Javier Yes.  (Or `return *pReal;` if the member is still a pointer and the function returns a reference.)

Comment: @aschepler, do you mind in editing your initial answer to see the method's implementation given that the private members are: `CMatrix<T> *pReal` and `CMatrix<T> *pImag`? Would it be `const CMatrix<T>& imagPart() const{ return (*this->pReal);}` and `CMatrix<T>& realPart(){ return (*this->pReal); }`?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a local variable for CComplexMat in your Foo class instead of just accessing the parent class to get the value of pReal.

This [tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/) breaks down the difference between friendship and inheritance in C++.
Note how they accessed the member variables of the parent class directly, without a local member of the parent class type.  This is likely what you want to do in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a protected member from outside a class, even if the class attempting the access is a sub class of the class that contains the protected member.

In your example, if pComplex would point to an object of type Foo, then you could access pReal in the way that you are attempting.

Answer (score 0):

According C++ standard about access of  protected members in derived classes (11.5)

> Except when forming a pointer to member (5.3.1), the access must be through a
>   pointer to, reference to, or object of the derived class itself (or any class derived from that class)

You are trying to access pReal through base class.

Make Foo friend of CComplexMat to access it's members.